# How do I modify an 'Any' variable by first checking for its type?

Tags: swift

I'm collecting statistics into a Dictionary:

```
var metrics = [String:Any]
```

These metrics can be Ints, Doubles, Strings, so I'm trying to use Any.

I initialize a metric like this:

```
metrics["sentBeacons"] = UInt(0)
```

But now if I try to modify it, the compiler throws an error:

```
metrics["sentBeacons"]! += 1 // Error: can't apply Int to Any?
```

Which I understand, it can't know that that key has an Int.

I tried:

```
if metrics["sentBeacons"] is UInt {
    metrics["sentBeacons"]! += 1
}
```

But no dice. I also tried typecasting:

```
if var sentBeacons = metrics["sentBeacons"] as? UInt {
    sentBeacons += 1
}
```

But this doesn't work either, because (I think) the Dictionary is a value type and I'm only accessing a copy of the variable.

How can I ask the compiler: "If this 'Any' is now an Int, then add '1' to it (in place)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update your dictionary with your new calculated value:

```
if var sentBeacons = metrics["sentBeacons"] as? UInt {
    sentBeacons += 1
    metrics["sentBeacons"] = sentBeacons
}
```

Comment: Dang it, you beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: I've been on both sides of that.  :)

Comment: So obvious, in retrospect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I made myself an extension for this, to encapsulate the read/modify/write steps when dealing with dictionaries:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func transformValue(forKey key: Key, valueTransformer: (oldValue: Value?) -> Value) -> Dictionary {
        var copy = self
        copy[key] = valueTransformer(oldValue: self[key])
        return copy
    }
}

metricts.transformValue(forKey: "sentBeacons"){UInt($0!) + 1}
```